# Single-Element-Vector Initialization in a Function Call

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, overload-resolution

Consider the following example code:

**Example:**

```
void print(int n) {
    cout << "element print\n";
}

void print(vector<int> vec) {
    cout << "vector print\n";
}

int main() {
   /* call 1 */ print(2);
   /* call 2 */ print({2});
   std::vector<int> v = {2};
   /* call 3 */ print(v);
   /* call 4 */ print( std::vector<int>{2} );
   return 0;
}
```

which generates the following output:

```
element print
element print
vector print
vector print
```

Why the call to `print` function (call 2 in above example) is getting matched to function accepting a single value? I am creating a vector (containing a single element) in this call, so should it not match to call to `print` with vector as input?

This is partially discussed [in an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975804/c11-vector-initialization-in-a-function-call) where the provided solution works for vectors with more than 1 elements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the 1st overload wins in the overload resolution for `print({2});`.

In both cases [copy list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) applies, for the 1st overload taking `int`,

(emphasis mine)

> Otherwise (if `T` is not a class type), **if the braced-init-list has only one element** and either `T` isn't a reference type or is a reference type that is compatible with the type of the element, `T` is direct-initialized (in direct-list-initialization) or copy-initialized (in copy-list-initialization), except that narrowing conversions are not allowed.

`{2}` has only one element, it could be used to initialize an `int` as the argument directly; this is an exact match.

For the 2nd overload taking `std::vector<int>`,

> Otherwise, the constructors of `T` are considered, in two phases:
>
> - All constructors that take `std::initializer_list` as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type `std::initializer_list`

That means an `std::initializer_list<int>` is constructed and used as the constructor's argument of `std::vector<int>` (to construct the argument for `print`). One user-defined conversion (via the constructor of `std::vector` taking one `std::initializer_list`) is required, then it's worse match than the 1st overload.

Answer (score 11):

`{2}` is a legal initializer for a number of types, including `int`. Overload resolution prefers a type that exactly matches to one that requires further construction.

Answer (score 2):

No thats not what you do, you`re creating an initializer_list.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Call 1) Single Element is called

Call 2) initializer_list creates an single int element

Call 3) A Vector object is given

Call 4) A Vector object is given

The Overload resulotion prefers to use the int parameter method before the std::vector parameter method, because there are less type conversions.
The int parameter is a direct match, for the vector parameter an additional conversion is needed.

For example:

```
void print(std::initializer_list<int> list){
    cout << "initializer_list print\n";
}
```

would result for call 2, that the output is "initializer_list print"

Comment: Important note: a braced initializer list is *type-less*, and not a `std::initializer_list`. So your first sentence is wrong.