# Avoid Conversion from single element vector to primitive type

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector

I have a problem with constant single element std::vector when pass through a function. C++ compiler automatically call wrong function when the std::vector variable contain a single element. This is though the policy of C++ design. However is there any explicit method to specify in such a case. Here are the examples of the problems

```
assume i have two overload functions both have the same name "foo"

void foo(const std::vector<int> A)
{
         // do vector operator
     printf("vector thing");
}


void foo(int a)
{
     // do integer operator
     printf("integer thing")
}
```

In general case both of these functions are called correctly

```
foo({1,2,3});    // print do vector thing
foo( 3 );        // print do integer thing
```

however from c++ rule. when call

```
foo({5});        // print do integer thing ( I want it to call as vector )
```

one of the methods is to create a variable

```
std::vector<int> B = { 5 };
```

in order to solve this problem.

I feel this method is a bit clumsy. Is there any method that can void the compiler to treat {5} as 5 and call foo(int a).

note:
here is the reference that explain what the problem is 
[c++11 single element vector initialization in a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565165/c11-single-element-vector-initialization-in-a-function-call)

Comment: Considering this is a great source of confusion, just write `std::vector` explicitly, and you have no problems.

Comment: `foo(std::vector<int>({5}));`

Answer (score 6):

You need another overload, taking `std::initializer_list` as a parameter:

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<int> A)
{
    foo(std::vector<int>(A.begin(), A.end()));
}
```

---

If you always call this function by creating vectors directly with `{...}`, rather than using `std::vector` variables, then you can remove `std::vector` overload completely and operate directly on `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 5):

No, because as of C++17 the rules explained on the linked answer still hold.

You can create a temporary instead of a variable, though.

```
foo(std::vector{5});      // C++17 with class type deduction
foo(std::vector<int>{5}); // older versions
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to disambiguate the function call is to make the integer overload a function template:

```
template <class Int> void foo(Int a)
{
   std::printf("generalized (maybe integer) thing\n");
}
```

This way, the invocation

```
foo({3});
```

will consider the non-templated function a better match while `foo(3)` instantiates and calls the function template. This because `{3}` is an `std::initializer_list<int>` with one element *in the context of type deduction*. You can also redirect to the original `foo(int a)` function like this:

```
void fooImpl(int a)
{
   std::printf("integer thing\n");
}

template <class Int> void foo(Int&& a)
{
   fooImpl(std::forward<Int>(a));
}
```

This refuses to compile when e.g. calling `foo` with an argument not convertible to an integer, which might be a desirable usage restriction. Also, it should be very unlikely that you encounter a performance overhead due to the forwarding intermediate function.