# Why does this code generate different output for different compilers?

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list, compiler-specific, direct-initialization

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct C {
  int a;

  C() : a(0) {}
  C(int a) : a(a) {}
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const C &c) {
  os << c.a;
  return os;
}

using T = std::vector<C>;

int main() {
  auto v = T({5});

  for (const auto &a : v) {
    std::cout << a << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If I use g++, it prints:

```
5,
```

If I use MS compiler, it prints:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Why are the results different?

Without `()` around `{5}`, the results, of course, are the same.

Comment: Could you paste up the compiler details please and possibly the command line too assuming you know how to extract that from MSVC. I think the MSVC compiler is at fault here, particularly if it's compiling to C++17 and onwards.

Comment: `> cl /EHsc a.cpp`                                                                                                                                                                         

`Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31630 for x86`

Comment: `std::vector<C> v = { 5 };` produces the expected result.

Comment: @ChrisMM As does `auto v = T{ { 5 } };`. Not sure which compiler has the bug, though. Clang-cl does the same as MSVC. I need to think about this one.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I spent about 30 minutes looking through the standard, and thought I found relevant passages, but none of the examples in it had this type of scenario.

Comment: A possible [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608388/wrong-overload-called-when-constructing-from-initializer-list-inside-parentheses), where `std::vector` is replaced by `testing::Test`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong overload called when constructing from initializer\_list inside parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608388/wrong-overload-called-when-constructing-from-initializer-list-inside-parentheses)

Answer (score 13):

This is *probably* a bug in the g++ compiler**<sup>§</sup>** (*not* in the MSVC compiler). The type of the `v` variable is (or *should be*, according to the Standard) a `std::vector<C>` containing 5 default-initialized elements.

Why? Because you use **direct initialization** (round brackets) rather than **list initialization** (curly braces, as in `auto v = T{ 5 }`). This direct initialization means that a constructor is called, and there is no constructor for `std::vector<T>` that takes a single, `T` argument.

This source of confusion is mentioned on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> Note that the presence of list-initializing constructor (10) means
> list initialization and direct initialization do different things:

Now, you *may* think that the compiler should be using that list-initializing constructor (as g++ does) … but it *shouldn't* be doing so! That constructor's argument is *not* of type `T` but of type `std::initializer_list<T>`; so, to call that constructor (using *direct initialization*), you would need `auto v = T({ { 5 } });` (note the extra set of braces). **<sup>†</sup>**

For your code, `auto v = T({ 5 });`, the closest-matched constructor is version #3 on the linked cppreference page (with the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> arguments defaulted), so the `{ 5 }` is treated as a `size_t` value for the count of elements initialized as `T()`. In fact, according to that same page, the defaulted 2<sup>nd</sup> argument version has been removed since C++11 – so the *only* match for your call is constructor version #4, which produces the same result.

In fact, clang (which gives the same result as MSVC for your code) warns about this ([see it on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5W7YxreP3)):

> warning : braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]

There are a number of ways you can force the initialization to a single-element vector with a `{5}` member. The simplest is to use list-initialization:

```cpp
auto v = T{ { 5 } }; // Or even: auto v = T{ 5 };
```

Another is to add an explicit `count` argument:

```cpp
auto v = T(1, { 5 }); // Or just: auto v = T(1, 5);
```

---

**<sup>§</sup>** I do not claim to be an authority when it comes to the rules a compiler should follow in order to conform to the C++ Standard(s), so I am prepared to accept that this *may* be a (rare) ambiguity in the Standard, rather than a bug or defect in the g++ compiler.

**<sup>†</sup>** Note that, although `{ 5 }` *can* be used as a valid `std::initializer_list<C>` (as it is in the case of `auto v = T{ 5 };`), in terms of overload resolution for function calls (including those to constructors), it is a better match for a single `size_t` value; see [Single-Element-Vector Initialization in a Function Call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46565165/10871073) (especially the top answer).

Comment: Why can't `{ 5 }` initialize the single argument in `vector::vector(std::initializer_list<T>)`? `C(int)` is not explicit. Though I would think that the `vector::vector(size_type)` constructor would beat it in overload resolution anyways, but only clang seems to think that: https://godbolt.org/z/7PKM481xa

Comment: @Artyer Yes, I think you're right. It's a case of a single-element initializer-list being converted to a `size_t`. See my edit and the newly-linked Q/A.

Comment: `GCC is actually the only compiler that implements this correctly in this case`: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109523

Comment: @Fedor I'm still not convinced. From what I can see, the single-element `std:initializer_list<T>` will resolve to an *actual* `T` object ... and there is no constructor of `std:vector<T>` that takes a single `T`. So the argument is considered as the `size_t count`.

Comment: ... adding the nested braces makes that single element *itself* an initializer-list, and there is a separate paragraph in the Standard that covers that case.

Comment: Also, `C` in the OP's code is not an aggregate class, because it has a user-defined constructor.

Comment: if I use `using T = std::vector<int>` instead of `using T = std::vector<C>`, the program prints `5, ` for both compilers (MSVC and G++).

Comment: Maybe [this paragraph](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#7.1) is the pertinent one?

Comment: Should we add a `language-lawyer` tag to this question?